# How to insert 1 image in 2 different directories using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to insert 1 image in 2 different directories but it is saving only in the first directory but not in the second directory.I am unable find the mistake in my code,please check the below code and help us.Thanks in advance.

```
public function image()
{ 
    $data = array();
    $error = array();
    $config1=array(
        'upload_path'=>'upload/',
        'allowed_types'=>'jpg|jpeg|png|bmp',
        'max_size'=>0,
        'filename'=>url_title($this->input->post('file'))
    );

    $this->load->library('upload',$config1);
    if($this->upload->do_upload('file')){
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($error);
        exit();
    }else {
        $fdata = $this->upload->data();
        $data['image'] = 'upload/' . $fdata['file_name'];
    }

    $config2=array(
        'upload_path'=>'upload/images/',
        'allowed_types'=>'jpg|jpeg|png|bmp',
        'max_size'=>0,
        'filename'=>url_title($this->input->post('file'))
    );
    $this->upload->initialize($config2);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('file')){
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($error);
        exit();
    } else {
        $fdata = $this->upload->data();
        $data['file2'] = 'upload/images' . $fdata['file_name'];
    }

    $data['name'] = $this->input->post('dname', TRUE);
    $data['email'] = $this->input->post('demail', TRUE);
    $data['mobile'] = $this->input->post('dmobile', TRUE);
    $data['mobile'] = $this->input->post('daddress', TRUE);

    $result = $this->insert_model->insert($data);
    $sdata = array();
    $sdata['message'] = "Well done!</strong> You successfully add the 
    Product Details.";
    $this->session->set_userdata($sdata);
    redirect('super_admin/add_product', 'refresh');
}
```

Comment: `$data['file2'] = 'upload/images' . $fdata['file_name'];`  to `$data['file2'] = 'upload/images/' . $fdata['file_name'];`

Comment: Have you checked in your upload directory? 
`images` dir is created there?

Comment: did you set the upload permission like 777  to second folder?

Comment: `$this->upload->initialize($config2);` to `$this->load->library('upload',$config2);`

Comment: What error are you getting in?

Comment: ya i checked in upload directory it is adding but upload/images directory it is not showing that image.

Comment: is it mandatory to set the 777 permission to second folder ,if it so can u tell me how to set

Comment: It will support only for first config to load. $this->load->library('upload',$config2) that's way i changed to $this->upload->initialize($config2).

Comment: i am not getting any error but image is not storing in 2 directories

Answer (score 1):

You should make a method for upload, so you can use it more times.

```
    /**
     * Upload a file.
     * 
     * @param $field
     * @param $upload_path
     * @param string $allowed_types
     * @return bool | file_name
     */
    public function do_upload($field, $upload_path, $allowed_types = 'jpg|png|gif')
    {
        $config['upload_path']          = $upload_path;
        $config['allowed_types']        = $allowed_types;
        $config['max_size']             = 500;
        $config['max_width']            = 1024;
        $config['max_height']           = 1024;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($field))
        {
            $this->upload = null; // Unload library
            return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            $data = $this->upload->data();
            $this->upload = null; // Unload library
            return $data["file_name"];
        }
    }
```

Now you can use it in image().

## Example

```
public function image()
{
    $data = array();

    // For 1st directory
    if ($data['image'] = $this->do_upload('your_filed_name', 'upload/')) {
       // Statements
        // $data['image'] = 'upload/' . $data['image']
    } else {
        $data['errors'] = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    }

    // For 2st directory
    if ($data['image'] = $this->do_upload('your_filed_name', 'upload/images/')) {
        // Statements
        // $data['image2'] = 'upload/images/' . $data['image']
    } else {
        $data['errors'] = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    }

    // Your rest of logic
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but problem still not yet rectified

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function image()
{ 
    $data = array();
    $error = array();
    $config1=array(
        'upload_path'=>'upload/',
        'allowed_types'=>'jpg|jpeg|png|bmp',
        'max_size'=>0,
        'filename'=>url_title($this->input->post('file'))
    );

    $this->load->library('upload',$config1,'file1'); // Create custom object for file 1 upload
    if($this->file1->do_upload('file')){
        $error = array('error' => $this->file1->display_errors());
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($error);
        exit();
    }else {
        $fdata = $this->file1->data();
        $data['image'] = 'upload/' . $fdata['file_name'];
    }

    $config2=array(
        'upload_path'=>'upload/images/',
        'allowed_types'=>'jpg|jpeg|png|bmp',
        'max_size'=>0,
        'filename'=>url_title($this->input->post('file'))
    );


    $this->load->library('upload', $config2, 'file2'); // Create custom object for file 2 upload
    $this->file2->initialize($config2);
    if (!$this->file2->do_upload('file')){
        $error = array('error' => $this->file2->display_errors());
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($error);
        exit();
    } else {
        $fdata = $this->file2->data();
        $data['file2'] = 'upload/images' . $fdata['file_name'];
    }

    $data['name'] = $this->input->post('dname', TRUE);
    $data['email'] = $this->input->post('demail', TRUE);
    $data['mobile'] = $this->input->post('dmobile', TRUE);
    $data['mobile'] = $this->input->post('daddress', TRUE);

    $result = $this->insert_model->insert($data);
    $sdata = array();
    $sdata['message'] = "Well done!</strong> You successfully add the 
    Product Details.";
    $this->session->set_userdata($sdata);
    redirect('super_admin/add_product', 'refresh');
}
```

Comment: i tried your code but still no change in my problem

Comment: Which server are you using? @RamuGampa

Comment: Apache  from XAMPP

Answer (score 0):

My problem resolved with following code:

```
    public function image()
    {    

            $config['upload_path']          = './upload/images';
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size']             = 0;
         $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){
       } else {
       $fdata = $this->upload->data();
    $data['file2'] = 'upload/images' . $fdata['file_name'];
       } 
            $config2=array(
    'upload_path'=>'upload/',
    'allowed_types'=>'jpg|jpeg|png|bmp',
    'max_size'=>0,
     );
     $this->upload->initialize($config2);

    if($this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){
   $data = array(
    'name' =>$this->input->post('name'),
   'email' =>$this->input->post('email'),
   'phone' =>$this->input->post('phone'),
   'title' =>$this->input->post('someField'),
   'image'=>$this->upload->file_name,
    );
    //Transfering data to Model
    $this->insert_model->add($data);
            }
            else
            {
                    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

                    $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
            }
     }
     }
```